# Is it possible to make a webHttpBinding WCF service to answer binary?

Tags: .net, wcf, binary, webhttpbinding

I implemented this contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{parameter}", BodyStyle= WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
byte[] Operation(string parameter);
```

But, when I called the implementation, all I got was something like this:

```
<base64Binary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">dGVzdA==</base64Binary>
```

Can't I remove this wrapper and this serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it return Stream.

```
Stream Operation(string parameter)
{
   ...
   new MemoryStream(bytes);
}
```